# erb partials with arguments for generating content

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass, erb

I've been playing around with sass and in doing so I've come across .erb files and how I can use them with partial files to generate a full html document. I'm wondering whether it is possible, and if so how, to create a partial .erb file that I can then render in the main html but using arguments to pass over as content. Similar I guess to how a mixin/function in sass can generate css?

I want to be able to pass a command to create a section that contains three columns, and within them a specified number of divs that contain lists.

```
div.section
  div.column
    ul
      li
      li
  div.column
    ul
      li
      li
      li
```

Anything you can provide as assistance, even just a simple example showing the syntax required would be super helpful in getting me on my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`content_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) helper for the section div and helper for ul list:

Erb code:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, class: 'section') do %>
   <%= ul_list([1,2]) %>
   <%= ul_list([1,2,3]) %>
<% end %>
```

`app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
 def ul_list(arr)
    content_tag :div, class: 'column' do
      content_tag :ul do
        concat(raw(arr.map { |l| content_tag(:li, l) }.join))
      end
    end
  end
```

Those code generate the HTML below:

```
   <div class="section">
        <div class="column">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer.

Can you elaborate on it for my benefit though please, sorry (!), I've not really done any rails work before and I'm just using .erb files in isolation. How would I get the helper.rb you've described to be referenced as I'm getting syntax errors just putting the erb code in the index.html.erb for example.

Is it necessary to structure things a certain way etc or is there a way of importing it into the file for use?

Comment: @Cigol could you share the error which you get? And how you use my example? It's unclear for me what you asking.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I get: SyntaxError at / index.html.erb:74: syntax error, unexpected ')' ...ag(:div, class: 'section') do ).to_s; @_out_buf << ' ... ^ index.html.erb:88: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' index.html.erb:90: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

*the way I'm using it* is via middleman, and I've defined your helper in the config.rb.

Comment: @Cigol first of all you tagged your question as `ruby-on-rails`, and it has nothing about `middleman`, second it's a syntax error `SyntaxError` - Raised when encountering Ruby code with an invalid syntax.

.